# Musical React App, Do I use EC2, Lightsail, or S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, deployment

I have a musical React App that I want to create that involves me uploading some audio files, creating relational databases for audio file interaction, as well as uploading graphics. I'd like to get opinions on whether I need to setup an EC2 instance, a LightSail instance, or use S3. If it sounds as if I'm confused, I am. Never used AWS for deployments and I want to make sure I'm not paying for the wrong things. Please help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to your project, the front end and the back end. These should be hosted separately.

**Frontend**
If you are using Webpack to bundle you React code and any other related assets(CSS, Images, SVG's, etc), you should upload these bundled assets into S3 and host these files. With the right configuration, S3 will let people that come to your domain to download these assets and view your website.

**Backend**
There are quite a few possible solutions, possibly the easiest solution for you would be to use Lambda and an RDS or Dynamo instance as this removes all the setup and confusion with deploying your own infrastructure.

If you were to not use Lambda, assuming you will not have a heap of traffic, you can create an EC2 instance and host whatever web server fits your purpose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!! Definitely helped me with what goes where. From my reading, I found that Lightsail is a combination of all of those entities into one. Is that a safe assumption?

Comment: @ByronBuyck No sorry, Light Sail is a very basic server hosting service offered by AWS, you could use it to host your application sure, but this depends on how tech savy you are with Linux for example, there are numerous alternatives that are better when compared to Light Sail, for example, Digital Ocean or Vultr.